# How to write sql convertible expression

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

Lets say i have an example like this:

I have many models. Every model has `location` somewhere, but in different place, for example it can be:
`foo.location` or `foo.bar.location`. Now i want to get some objects from the database filtered by location, for example

```
var firstLocation = new Location(5, 10);
var secondLocation = new Location(20, 15);

var results = dbSet.Where(x => 
    x.foo.location.xcord >= firstLocation.xcord && x.foo.location.xcord <= secondLocation.xcord &&
    x.foo.location.ycord >= firstLocation.ycord && x.foo.location.ycord <= secondLocation.ycord

)
```

Now i want to extract this expression inside Where to some function that returns expression like that based on selector which shows where inside object is location object:

`dbSet.Where(GetLocationExpression(x => x.foo.bar, firstLocation, secondLocation))`

How to achieve that? I use EF Core and i want it to be convertible to sql.

I tried:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetLocationExpression<T>(Func<T, Location> locationSelector, Location firstLocation , Location secondLocation)
        {
            return x => 
            locationSelector(x).xcord >= firstLocation.xcord && locationSelector(x).xcord <= secondLocation.xcord 
            &&
            locationSelector(x).ycord >= firstLocation.ycord && locationSelector(x).ycord <= secondLocation.ycord
        }
```

But it throws error taht this query could not be translated to SQL.
I also would like to add sometimes something to it like:

```
dbSet.Where(x => x.Name = "something" && GetLocationExpression(x => x.foo.bar, firstLocation, secondLocation))
```

Or just optional parameter in GetLocationExpression method for any additional filters

Comment: See  [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) which will output the SQL to the IDE Output window.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) for such task, which will do expression substitution automatically.

```
private Expression<Func<Location, Location, Location, bool>> GetLocationExpression<T>()
{
    return (locationSelector, firstLocation, secondLocation) => 
          locationSelector.xcord >= firstLocation.xcord && locationSelector.xcord <= secondLocation.xcord 
       && locationSelector.ycord >= firstLocation.ycord && locationSelector.ycord <= secondLocation.ycord
}
```

And usage:

```
dbSet
   .AsExpandable() // important, we have to switch to LINQKit expression preprocessor
   .Where(x => x => x.Name = "something" 
      && GetLocationExpression().Invoke(x.foo.bar, firstLocation, secondLocation))
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without using third party lib? I don't really want to add whole library for single use case. There must be some way.

Comment: No way. Or just do not use EF ;) LINQKit is well known library developed by LINQPad creator.

Comment: Also LINQKit has PredicateBuilder - very useful thing. Any good developer have invented wheel in this area.